# DateTime Custom format

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got the following String format: "26/10/2017 22:54:22"

im trying to convert it to DateTime object, which should be of the same format as the string (24hours format) but somewhy it generates a 12h format.

my code:

```
var time = "26/10/2017 22:54:22";
            DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine(convertedDate);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

the output i get is: 10/26/2017 10:54:22 PM

any ideas why is that?

Comment: because your normal date format is month/day/year 12h clock?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` outputs depending on current culture settings. Check if your machine uses American date with 12h format.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto isn't this rather an answer than a comment?

Comment: you can simply force the datetime to use your format: `Console.WriteLine(convertedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto is there anything i can do to prevent it? not to depend on culture settings?

Comment: You can use date-time format string manipulation either by `ToString` or `string.Format` with specified formatting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277622/interpreting-dates-console-writeline-vs-string-format for similar issue.

Comment: There are a ton of answers to this question already.... did you even bother to look?

Comment: @MongZhu my goal isn't to convert it to a string. i want it to be a DateTime object with the format i mentioned

Comment: _"i want it to be a DateTime object with the format i mentioned"_ `DateTime` objects _don't have_ formats.  They represent a moment in time.  How you choose to print it out on screen is up to you.

Comment: `DateTime` itself is a struct, which has no specific format provided. What you can do is setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` if you don't want to change machine's regional settings.

Comment: @gilleibovitz see the comment by James Thorpe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` by itself doesn't make any difference if the time is 12-hour or 24-hour, it's only when converted to a string that there is a difference.

`Console.WriteLine` will call the `ToString()` method (the one without any parameters) of the object passed as parameter. For a `DateTime`, `ToString()` formats the date and time according to the current locale. Yours is probably set to a 12-hour format.

If you need to print your time with a different format, you should format the `DateTime` explicitely, using another variant of the `ToString` method.

In your case:

```
Console.WriteLine(convertedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have successfully parsed into a `DateTime` structure, there is overloaded method of `ToString` for `DateTime`, which is converts the value of the current `DateTime` object to its equivalent string representation using the specified format and the formatting conventions of the current culture.

So in your case you can just use:

```
Console.WriteLine(convertedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

MSDN Link: [DateTime.ToString Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)